# .htaccess does not rewrite one URL

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteRule   ^One/?$    /xxyy/xxyy111.php [NC]
RewriteRule   ^Two/?$    /xxyy/xxyy222.php [NC]
RewriteRule   ^Three/?$   /xxyy/xxyy333.php [NC]
```

One and Three display just fine in that the URL in the browser's address bar looks like this:

```
https://mywebsite/One
```

or

```
https://mywebsite/Three
```

but two is

```
https://mywebsite/xxyy/xxyy222.php
```

and I cannot figure out where to look for why this is happening.

Apparently it was a matter of signaling (my guess) Apache to update its rules. I made a change to .htaccess by pointing it to a non-existent file, then back to the original file and now it is working corectly.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is you need to use `[L]` in your rules to prevent it from continuing when a match is found.

```
RewriteRule ^One/?$ /xxyy/xxyy111.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Two/?$ /xxyy/xxyy222.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Three/?$ /xxyy/xxyy333.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: That may help but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: You need to try and clear your browser cache. It caches rules usually so you might be running into that. That rule should work just fine.